# Multi Project Maven using single POM

Tags: maven

I have various projects (lets say Project 1, project 2, project 3 etc....). They are in different repositories in the BitBucket.
Some of these Projects share the same Versions. I wanted to check if I can use a Super Parent POM ? I want the Projects to listen to the Parent POM for Version changes, is this possible ? Did google around however dint find any useful information on this.

[image]

Any pointers will be helpful

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use one parent POM for all you projects no matter where you store them. The only requirement is that that POM is deployed in a Maven repository and is available in any of that projects. It can be Maven Central or JCenter or your corporate Maven repository like Artifactory or Nexus. Actually, a lot of open-source projects depend on so-called `oss-parent` POMs. [Take a look at Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/pom.xml#L7-L10), for example, it depends on [sonatype/oss-parents](https://github.com/sonatype/oss-parents). Some companies make their own parents, like [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML/oss-parent).

The answer to second question is generally "no". You cannot simply "watch" for the version changes in such parent POMs, unless you:

1. Own them. The easiest way. You can trigger downstream builds, or fire alarms, or automatically create issues / tickets in children POMs whenever you update parent POM.
2. Configure you CI/CD to do that. Basically, it's the same as 1, but you just have to watch for the updates and trigger things.
3. Use third-party service that will do that. Once, there was one called [VersionEye](https://github.com/versioneye), but they are gone. I've heard that [Snyk](https://snyk.io/) is doing something similar.